# Use a loop to generate n number of new variables

Tags: python, variables

I'm looking to allow a user choice to control the generation of a user define number of lists (or other items)

Essentially my code allows the user to bring in a list of films/games/etc. then split them into a number of different tiers by assigning a score between 1 and N, where N is their choice. Then in each tier, each item faces off against the other to allow the user to pick their favourite. Originally there was no tiering at all - just a match between each combination of items. This work, but can be a huge number of matches - the tiering shrinks things down.

Anyway, I can't figure out how to take the users scores for a ganme an split the games into N number of lists. Obviously if I dictate the number of tiers, I can generate that number of empty lists and then append to each depending on the score chosen (I did this at first with 3 tiers) but I can't create N number of empty lists. The current pertinent code is:

```
def scores(my_games):
    global NumT
    global big_dict
    big_dict = {}
    NumT = input("How many tiers would you like to divide the list into? \n" "Fewer tiers will result in more battles. \n" "It is recommended to use between 2 and 5 tiers.")
    while NumT.isdigit() == False:
        print("Oops! That was not a number. Try again...")
        NumT = input("Choose a number of tiers")
    NumT = int(NumT)
    print(NumT)
    print(f'For each game give it a score of between 1 and {NumT} to divide the games into {NumT} tiers')
    for item in my_games:
        score = (input(f' Score 1 - {NumT}: {item}'))
        while score.isdigit() == False:
            print("Oops!  That was not a number.  Try again...")
            score = (input(f' Score 1 - {NumT}: {item}'))
        score = int(score)
        if score not in range (1, NumT+1, 1):
            print(f'That number is not between 1 and {NumT}. Try again....')
            score = int(input(f' Score 1 - {NumT}: {item}'))
        big_dict[item] = score


def make_tiers(big_dict, NumT):
    print(NumT)
    for n in range (1, NumT+1):
        print(n)
        keys = [k for k, v in big_dict.items() if v == n]
    print(keys)
```

The first functions works fine. My idea was to pack up the games and the tier choice into a dictionary (with game name as key since the tiers would duplicate as keys), then use the values ito extract the keys for a given value (a given tier). This is what the second function does, but I don't know how to write each set of keys to a different variable. I had hoped I could use the changing value of "n" to change the variable name but I don't know to (I can write a list of empty lists I can pick from as I don't know how many empty lists I need in advance)

Sort of figured it out:

```
def make_tiers(big_dict, NumT):
    print(NumT)
    for n in range (1, NumT+1):
        print(n)
        keys = [k for k, v in big_dict.items() if v == n]
        globals()["list"+str(n)] = keys
```

This gets me my lists

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. I can't understand your description of the problem, and I don't understand what part of the code you think is failing. For example, if you think you have *working* code to ask the user for inputs, then instead of showing code that asks for that input, hard-code an input value and explain what the code should do *with that hard-coded input*. If the problem is with the actual request for input, then show an *isolated* code example of the technique you are trying to use.

Comment: "but I don't know how to write each set of keys to a different variable" I don't follow. Why not just use the dictionary as is? What exactly do you want to happen instead?

Comment: Ok, I have obviously explained myself poorly. Perhaps I included too much unnecessary code in my question.

Comment: In essense, I want to take a list and split it into a number of different lists. The number of lists is decided by the user. When items from the first list go into which of the new lists is also decided by the user. There are presented with each item in turn and asked which list  they want the item to go into. The crux is I don't know how to dynamically generate a given number of new unique lists

Comment: Goddam my typos are shocking! Sorry

Comment: "In essense, I want to take a list and split it into a number of different lists." So... make a list of lists? Like, you start with `[]`, and then when you append an element to it, the element you're appending is a list? Why is this difficult? "The crux is I don't know how to dynamically generate a given number of new unique lists" You don't ask this question for "... new unique integers". You just make a list, and put the integers into it. Same thing for lists.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to make a list of lists. You say start with []? I get that, but do I not need to define the list first. If I want to, say, put 3 lists into 1 list, I need to create this three lists first, no? So I need to start with 3 empty lists? I am genuinely asking. If I have to create the empty lists first (List_1, List_2, List_3 etc) I am still stuck, because I don't know how many lists I need in advance

Comment: "If I want to, say, put three integers into 1 list, I need to compute these values first, right? So do I need three separate variables for them?" No, of course not; even if you wanted to assign a name for them explicitly, you could re-use the name - since you won't be referring to them by name *after* putting them in the list.

Comment: I am so confused. Never mind about putting lists into lists. I just want to create N different lists. If I want to output N lists, these lists need a unique variable name. How do I write code that will produce N lists with N unique names?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238796/discussion-between-karl-knechtel-and-mwallace).

Comment: Sort of figured it out: